# ASP.NET MVC - Rendering Accented Characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-encode

I have a problem rendering accented characters of French, Spanish etc. in my view.

For eg.
Instead of rendering `Olá` it renders as `Ol&#225;`

I did try `@Html.Raw(myVariable)`. It did work.
However, it is very tiresome to use this across my application.
Is there a way or solution to make this work across my application?

I tried this

```
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: What values can we expect in `myVariable`?

Comment: It is a Model property that can contain words like "Buenos días" that is a translation for "Good Morning".

Comment: And what *exactly* is present in the string: a single character **`í`** or an entity code such as **`&‌iacute;`** ?

Comment: The string contains the correct word when I add it in the watch. But on the screen while rendering it shows differently. Eg "`&#237`" instead of an `í`.

Comment: That means your source text has already been HTML-Encoded somewhere. Maybe it is stored HTML-Encoded in the database, or maybe it gets HTML-Encoded when the text is put into the Model. To prevent the whole situation, don't store HTML encoded text in the database and don't put HTML encoded text in the Model properties.

Comment: I got you. But, for now without having the access to the data in the database, is there something that we can use as a work around please?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the need for using `Html.Raw()`, you have these options:

1. Avoid storing HTML encoded text in your database;
2. Avoid putting HTML encoded text in variables/properties of type `string`;
3. If all you have is HTML encoded text, then you can use type [`MvcHtmlString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) for your variables/properties, and then Razor will refrain from encoding:

   ```
   var myEncodedVariable = MvcHtmlString.Create(myVariable);
   ```

   and then in Razor:

   ```
   @myEncodedVariable
   ```

   although I agree this is little more than using a different workaround at a different location.